# bash regular expression get string up to last specific character

Tags: regex, bash

Lets say I have strings

```
TEST='skjd fsd(fghf)h gfjgh(gh jfgh)ghnfg hhg)gfng df'
```

and I want to extract everything up the last closing parenthesis. I will not know how many parenthesis there are or length of the string. My output needs to be

```
skjd fsd(fghf)h gfjgh(gh jfgh)ghnfg hhg)
```

Right now, using sed ( `sed 's/).*//'` ) I am getting up the the first closing parenthesis but I need up the the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
TEST='skjd fsd(fghf)h gfjgh(gh jfgh)ghnfg hhg)gfng df'
echo $TEST | sed -n 's/\(.*[)]\)[^)]*/\1/p'
```

The output:

```
skjd fsd(fghf)h gfjgh(gh jfgh)ghnfg hhg)
```

`\(.*[)]\)` - the first capturing group, captures all characters till the last `)`

---

***grep*** alternative:

```
echo $TEST | grep -Po '.+\)(?=[^)]*$)'
```

---

one more ... ***perl*** approach:

```
echo $TEST | perl -nle 'print $1 if /(.+\))[^)]*$/'
```

---

and the last one ... is **awk** approach:

```
echo $TEST | awk -F')' -v OFS=')' '{$NF=""}1'
```

---

As you see, there are many ways to achieve the goal )

Comment: @sorontar, feel free to add your own answer. I've posted enough approaches

Answer (score 3):

Without using any regex in BASH you can use string substitution:

```
str='skjd fsd(fghf)h gfjgh(gh jfgh)ghnfg hhg)gfng df'

echo "${str%)*})"
```

This will get following output:

```
skjd fsd(fghf)h gfjgh(gh jfgh)ghnfg hhg)
```

`%)*` will remove all the text starting from **rightmost** `)` to the end.

In case you must use a regex then you can use:

```
[[ $str =~ ^.*\) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"

skjd fsd(fghf)h gfjgh(gh jfgh)ghnfg hhg)
```

`^.*\)` will match upto **the last `)`** since `.*` is a **greedy match**.

Comment: Though bash is preferred but here is a shorter sed: `sed 's/[^)]*$//' <<< "$str"`

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^)]*$//' <<< "${TEST}"
```

Edit:
@anubhava posted this answer as a comment to his own answer just a few seconds before I posted it. And he is right, bash is better.

Comment: But OP prefers slowest of all the options available :)